# I need assistance with understanding the / and % symbol from Java. Also, I need some advice on how to proceed with the code

Tags: java, bluej

Alright, let us start off, by showing my question.

### The Problem:

10001st prime

By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.

### What is the 10 001st prime number?

This is what I currently have down. I'm pretty bad at creating algorithms, but I truly have the desire to follow in my Father's path of being a IT. I enjoy doing this a lot, but I'm struggling right now.

```
public class PrimeNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         int primeNum = 2;

         for (int count = 0; count < 10002; count++)
         {
              if (primeNum / 2 ==  && primeNum / primeNum == 1)
         {
              primeNum++;
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Error.");
         }
     }
     System.out.println(primeNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S, I'm merely asking for assistance and guidance, so don't be hesitate to give me feedback.

Comment: 10,001st prime number does not mean that there are 10,001 primes between 1 and 10,001.  You'll need to supply yourself with integers until you have found over 10K primes.

Comment: What do you mean by "possible duplicate?"

Comment: @uthark:  I'm not convinced this is a duplicate at all.  It doesn't ask the same question.

Comment: I'm trying to scroll through and check all the numbers. @Makoto

Comment: No, you're only checking the first 10,001 numbers.  There are *significantly* less primes in that range than 10,001.

Comment: I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

The / symbol means 'divided by'. So your code says 'if primeNum divided by 2 = 1 and primeNum divided by primeNum = 1 then increase primeNum.' This is unnecessary; all this is asking is if primeNum is 2.

The % symbol means 'remainder when divided by'. So 2%3 = 1. 4%2=0. This will probably be useful in your program, because it will allow it to check to see if your number is prime by seeing if it is divisible by any numbers.

(With if (a%b==0), you can check to see if b is a factor of a.)

There are a few shortcuts your program could take: it only needs to check every prime number up to the square root of the number it is checking.

So you may want to keep an array of all prime numbers you have found, so that you can check if a number you want to know if it's prime is divisible by any of them.

(This can be done with a loop on the outside, going through every number, and a loop inside that loop, checking to see if that number is divisible by any of the previously discovered prime numbers.)

Comment: If you still have trouble I can supply sample code.

Comment: Thank you, all I needed was a few explanations. I am able to code for myself.